# Convert Directed Multigraph to Directed Simple Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, hash, directed-graph

I am given a directed multigraph (a graph which may contain self-loops and multiple edges between two vertices) and am tasked with converting it into a directed simple graph (a graph with no self-loops and only one edge allowed between vertices) in O(V + E) time and space. I am given the adjacency list for the directed multigraph and must convert it into another adjacency list for the directed simple graph.

[image]

Initially, I thought of running through the adjacency list of G and running each edge through a hash function and into a hash table. If there were any collisions, the edge would not be stored. Then, after running through every edge, I would convert the hash table back into an adjacency list. While this would take O(V + E) time, it would take up more than O(V + E) space for the allocation of the hash table.

Can anyone explain how they might go about tackling this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't the hash have O(E) size? Anyway, you can also do this per node.

Comment: All you're really doing is removing duplicates from each list of connected nodes. Just change each list of nodes to a hashset or some other structure that doesn't have duplicates. Your space complexity stays the same.